# Where can I read Vijnanabhiksu's commentary on Yoga Sutras?

Tags: translation-request, yoga-sutras

I would like to read Vijnanabhiksu's commentary on Yoga Sutras in English and Sanskrit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vijnana Bhikshu's major works on Yoga Darshana are:

- **Yoga Bhashya Vartika**, commentary on Yoga Sutras of Patanjali
- **Yoga Sara Sangraha** (Quintessence of Yoga)

You can get Yoga Vartika *Sanskrit text with English translation* from Internet Archive available in four volume per four Pada of Yoga Sutras of Patanjali.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

- [Yoga Sutra Bhashya Vartika Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/YogasutraBhashyaVartikaOfSankaraVol1RukmaniT.S.MRML) (Samadhipada)
- [Yoga Sutra Bhashya Vartika Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/YogasutraBhashyaVartikaOfSankaraVol2RukmaniT.S.MRML) (Sadhanapada)
- [Yoga Sutra Bhashya Vartika Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/YogasutraBhashyaVartikaOfSankaraVol3RukmaniT.S.MRML) (Vibhutipada)
- [Yoga Sutra Bhashya Vartika Volume 4](https://archive.org/details/YogasutraBhashyaVartikaOfSankaraVol4RukmaniT.S.MRML) (Kaivalyapada)

You can also find  [Yoga Sara Sangraha](https://archive.org/details/anenglishtransl00fundgoog) from Internet Archive.

Answer (score 1):

The link to these copies is dead - are there any other links please to the yoga vartika of vijnanabhiksu in English

Comment: Kindly extent comments into the comment sections, than writing another answer to post comments. Thank You.