# Vedas as authoritative but not eternal?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, belief

What if someone unequivocally accepts vedas as the Supreme authority for their philosophical and theological beliefs, but do not concur with them being either God authored or eternal (*Apauruṣeyā*) ?

Will that render them as *nāstika* or *āstika* ?

Have there been or are there, any such philosophers or eminent personalities or school of Thought with this kind of reasoning and beliefs?

Comment: they are astika, they are same as Samkhya  school of thought

Comment: @DarkKnight - I think there's a difference

Comment: yes there can be a difference

Comment: I don't thing there is a school in Hinduism that is equal to the one your are saying in the question

Comment: Why would you accept them as supreme if they have the possibility of faults?

Comment: @mar there's a big difference between considering something as Supreme and unequivocally authoritative.

Comment: @mar one can consider their parents as Supreme despite knowing that they being humans themselves might have their own faults.

Comment: @Vivikta - good point. however, there is an acharya even for parents. so if parents say - go to this acharya and consider him supreme, then you can get permission from parents to consider someone else as supreme

Comment: @mar again, acharya having taken a material form might have some fault, but, it's our belief and devotion that must transcends those faults of him and see him as 'Brahman' itself. However, for a third person (who isn't concerned in any way with us) me and my acharya, might  very well be two normal humans with lots of faults.

Comment: @Vivikta - we're quibbling about objective supreme vs subjective supreme. subjective supreme (what you're talking about) has a different definition, based on degree of devotion. objective supreme (what i'm talking about) has a different definition, based on degree of faults.

Comment: @mar - Yes dear, you're unequivocally & absolutely right! Let's make it rest then!  :))

Comment: @DarkKnight That is wrong. The Nyaya and Nirukta (and probably others) schools believe the Vedas to be authored by God AND authoritative.

Comment: @mar They won't have faults when they are authored by God.

Comment: @Ikshvaku I am not saying any thing about nyaya, my comments was about Samkhya. Because they believe vedas to be authorless and non eternal.

Comment: @DarkKnight Oh ok. And it looks like OP edited his question after I made the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Astika schools are those which accept Vedas as valid proof and do not depend whether they are authored or eternal.

Out of the six [astika darshanas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44476/what-are-the-different-schools-of-thoughts-in-hinduism-and-what-is-the-differenc/44487#44487) of sanatana dharma, four do not agree that the vedas are authorless and eternal.  All these six schools, however, accepted Vedas as valid proof (Shabda Pramana) and authortative. Thus they are considered astika darshana as opposed to Buddhism/Charvaka etc.

Samkhya & Yoga believes that the Vedas are non eternal. The Nyaya & Vaisheshika believe that the Vedas are authored by God and non eternal. Only the Mimamsa and Vedanta schools believe that Vedas are Apauruṣeyā and eternal.

Now what are the arguments put forth by these schools and how are they refuted? For this we have to refer to Mímáṃsá by the holy sage Jaimini.

The detailed arguments are provided in the [sarva-darshana-samgraha](https://archive.org/details/Sarva-Darsana-Samgraha.by.Madhavacharya-Vidyaranya.tr.by.E.B.Cowell/page/n195/mode/2up). Please read from page 187 onwards. It is around 10 pages.

> **Nyaya:** how can the Vedas be said to be underived from any personal author, when there is no evidence to establish this? Would you
> maintain that they have no personal author because, although there is
> an unbroken line of tradition, there is no remembrance of any
> author...The sentences of the Veda must have originated from a
> personal author, since they have the character of sentences like those
> of Kálidása and other writers. And, again, the sentences of the Veda
> have been composed by a competent person, since, while they possess
> authority, they have, at the same time, the character of sentences,
> like those of Manu and other sages.
>
> **Mimamsaka:** I shall now [says the Mímáṃsaka] clear up the whole question. What is meant by this paurusheyatva ["derivation from a
> personal author"] which it is sought to prove? ...For the sentences of
> the Veda are universally defined to be sentences which prove things
> that are not provable by other evidence. But if you could establish
> that these Vedic sentences only prove what is provable by other
> evidence, this definition would be at once contradicted, just as if a
> man were to say that his mother was a barren woman.

And it ends with

> Therefore as the Veda is thus proved to have not originated from any
> personal author, and as the minutest germ of suspicion against it is
> thus absolutely destroyed, we hold it as satisfactorily demonstrated
> that it has a self-established authority in all matters relating to
> dharma

Remember, Nyaya argues that the Vedas are authored by God so it is faultless. Mimansa does not accept Ishvara and Vedanta does not accept God to be an author of the Vedas. The arguments are that  Mimansa and Vedanta hold sound is eternal and the vedas are sounds and the vibrations of the air "manifest" the always existing sound. Thus vedas do not have authors in the traditional sense. Therefore, even Ishvara, who is faultness and infalliable, is not considered to be an author. This is also argued extensively in the above texts and the references therein.

The two answers below provide more details.

[Nyaya school](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45000/what-are-the-arguments-of-nyaya-and-samkhya-against-the-eternity-of-the-vedas/45010#45010)

[Samkhya/Yoga school](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/which-schools-of-indian-philosophy-consider-the-vedas-to-be-apauru%E1%B9%A3eya-authorle)

Comment: It very well explains several doubts. But even so then, those schools namely - 1. *Samkhya & Yoga* and 2. *Nyaya & Vaisheshika*, although considering *Vedas* as non-eternal, do consider its authors as either authorless - 1(अपौरुषेय) and God as the author - 2,respectively . Thus doubts on the asked questions remains.

Comment: @Vivikta I have added several discussion/references to the answer now.

Comment: thanks, it's a nice answer by you, **still each school atleast attributes vedas to either God or as being authorless (*Apauruṣeyā*)**. And my doubt still remains unresolved about the question(s) asked.  How Vedas being authorless and and yet non eternal, must be reconciled with? Doesn't strike to me somehow.

Comment: Only yoga school says it is authorless and non-eternal. Nyaya says it is authored by God and non-eternal. Vedanta says it is authorless and eternal. Non-eternal means it appears again and again in each yuga.

Comment: okay, now including the concepts of cyclic time in this for now, makes it a totally different concept.