# Did samakhys refuted the advaita vedanta's claim, existence of Brahman?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, argument, samkhya

Since samkhya is a atheistic school, they reject God(Brahman) . But advaita vedanta believe in a God that is Brahman so did any Samkhya philosopher ever refuted advaita vedanta on existence of Brahman?

Comment: Their viewpoint is given on Wikipedia.  Although it works much better on a moral God than an amoral one.
 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya#:~:text=Samkhya%20believes%20that%20the%20puru%E1%B9%A3a,atheistic%20realism%20and%20uncompromising%20dualism.

Comment: It kind of makes me wonder why they even bother to make such a long argument when a solely moral God can be easily disproved by the simple fact all of the supposed arguments work perfectly well if you flip them for a purely evil God.

Comment: Sāṅkhya is not atheistic per say. It's difficult to describe in English terms.

Comment: @Vivikta *'Aph. 46. * They [the Vedas,] are not the work of [the Supreme] Man; because **there is no such thing as the [Supreme] Man,** [whom you allude to as being, possibly,] their maker'*.[Source](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29556/22556) this means there is no God according to Samkhya

Comment: No corporeal god. A god with form (body) is unequivocally denied.

Answer (score 4):

No they don't. They rather agree with Non Dual singular existence.

> Aph. 150. (The Vedantins say, that,) there being a difference in its
> investments, **moreover, multiplicity attaches (seemingly,) to the one
> (Soul)**; as is the case with Space, by reason of jars, &c., (which
> mark out the spaces that they occupy).
>
> Aph. 152. Thus, (i.e., by taking the Sankhya view,) **there is no
> imputation of contradictory conditions to (a Soul** p. 170 supposed to
> be) **everywhere present as one** (infinitely extended monad).
>
> Aph. 154. **There is no opposition to the Scriptures (declaratory) of
> the non-duality (of Soul)**; because the reference (in such texts,) is
> to the genus, (or to Soul in general).

([Sankhya Sutras Book 1](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/kapila/kapila.asp) )

Comment: Most teachers ive heard (papaji, Nisargadatta) either say God exists sometimes and turn around and say He’s a myth the next. Or even say directly he does and doesnt exist. Maharshi says everything is just the Self, then says trust God he is infinitely more intelligent than you.